# node-horseman failing with phantomjs-prebuilt

Tags: node.js, ssl, phantomjs, node-modules, node-horseman

So I have been banging my head against a wall all day trying to figure out what the issue is but have yet to find a solution. I have posted all the npm modules, test code, and output below. When I install "phantomjs@1.9" using npm the test code works fine below but when I update to the latest phantomjs-prebuilt module the code below fails.

I am basically trying to using phantomjs to browse around Hulu and take screenshots of different pages.

I have read up on the changes between 1.9 and > 2.0 and it seems like some SSL changes have been made. When I "ps aux | grep phantom" I get the following process info:

> /huntsman/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs --load-images=true --ssl-protocol=any --ignore-ssl-errors=true --web-security=false /Users/pherlihy/work/huntsman/node_modules/node-phantom-simple/bridge.js

As far as I know based on my research setting "web-security=false", "ssl-protocol=any" and "ignore-ssl-errors=true" should fix any problems but that has yet to work.

If anyone has any ideas please let me know, thanks.

For reference I am using:

> "node-horseman": "^3.2.0"
>
> "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.14"

The test code I am using:

```
var Horseman = require('node-horseman');

//Create the Horseman instance
var horseman = new Horseman({
  timeout: 10000,
  injectJquery: true,
  ignoreSSLErrors: true,
  webSecurity: false
})

//User agent
.userAgent().then(function(arg_ua)
{
  console.log(arg_ua);
  return this;
})

//Viewport
.viewport(1280, 720)

//Open
.open('http://hulu.com')

//Success
.then(function()
{
  console.log('success!');
})

.catch(function(arg_error)
{
  console.log(arg_error);
});
```

The output I am getting using:

> DEBUG=horseman,horseman:verbose

```
node index.js 
  horseman using PhantomJS from phantomjs-prebuilt module +0ms
  horseman .setup() creating phantom instance 1 +5ms
  horseman phantom created +1s
  horseman phantom version 2.1.1 +17ms
  horseman page created +12ms
  horseman phantomjs onLoadFinished triggered success NaN +8ms
  horseman injected jQuery +23ms
  horseman .userAgent() get +12ms
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/538.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) PhantomJS/2.1.1 Safari/538.1
  horseman .viewport() set 1280 720 +0ms
  horseman .open() http://hulu.com +4ms
  horseman phantomjs onLoadFinished triggered fail 1 +3s
Error: Failed to GET url: http://hulu.com
    at checkStatus (/home/horseman/node_modules/node-horseman/lib/actions.js:78:16)
    at PassThroughHandlerContext.finallyHandler (/home/horseman/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/finally.js:56:23)
    at PassThroughHandlerContext.tryCatcher (/home/horseman/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/home/horseman/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:510:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/home/horseman/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:567:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/home/horseman/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:612:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/home/horseman/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:691:18)
    at Promise._fulfill (/home/horseman/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:636:18)
    at /home/horseman/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/nodeback.js:42:21
    at /home/horseman/node_modules/node-phantom-simple/node-phantom-simple.js:60:18
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/horseman/node_modules/node-phantom-simple/node-phantom-simple.js:645:9)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
  horseman phantomjs onLoadFinished triggered success 2 +4s
  horseman jQuery not injected - already exists on page +5ms
```